# Calculate the percentage growth from two values in a txt/csv file (Python)

Tags: python, calculation

I have a file `"Dow.txt"` formated as follows: `name, symbol, exchange, industry, value0, value1, value2, value3` for each of the 30 stocks in the Dow Jones Industrial Average.

How can I determine the best and worst-performing stocks in 2013 with regards to percentage growth? The possible outcome as shown below:

```
Best performing stock: stock name, percentage of growth
Worst performing stock: stock name, percentage of growth
```

I don't know how to tell the program to know which is the start price and which is the end price, so I don't know how to begin with the calculation.

So the tasks are:

- read file
- get values of the columns
- calculate percentage difference
- output the result

the file link as below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/107pPSYgSrjEVdqR7QZW1W2l6QP8n-18g/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Some more information is needed. Are you using pandas?

Comment: It's impossible to calculate percentage growth, as this is just one point in time.

Comment: first: What did you try so far?
second: If I've got you correct, you want the percentage growth from tha value in the 12/31/2012 column to the calue in the 12/31/2013 column. right?

Comment: @lefrcom, yes that's what im doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution without using any imports:

```py
def lines(file: str):
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line

def parse(lines):
    for line in lines:
        yield line.split(",")

def get_percentage_growth(path):
    line = lines(path)
    best = {"name": None, "percentage": float('-inf')}
    worst = {"name": None, "percentage": float('inf')}
    for row in parse(line):
        first, second = float(row[4]), float(row[5])
        percentage = (second-first)/first * 100
        if percentage > best["percentage"]:
            best["name"] = row[0]
            best["percentage"] = percentage
        if percentage < worst["percentage"]:
            worst["name"] = row[0]
            worst["percentage"] = percentage
    return best, worst

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = "data.txt"
    b, w = get_percentage_growth(f)
    print(f'Best performing stock: {b["name"]}, {b["percentage"]}')
    print(f'Worst performing stock: {w["name"]}, {w["percentage"]}')
```

assuming that the python file is located in the same directory as the data.txt file, this hsould work. The benefit is that this method is able to deal with files of TB due to the generators.